# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un dato boolean a string y cambiar su contenido de una API en Ionic con TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic

Este es mi archivo ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-apiferiados',
templateUrl: './apiferiados.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./apiferiados.page.scss'],
})
export class ApiferiadosPage implements OnInit {

  feriados: Datos[] = [];


constructor( private feriado:ServiceapiService) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.feriado.getFeriados().subscribe(resp => {
    console.log('feriados',resp);
    this.feriados.push(...resp.data);
});
}

}
```

y este el archivo de interface:

```
export interface RespuestaTopHeadlines {
status: string;
data: Datos[];
}

export interface Datos {
title: string;
date: string;
type: string;
inalienable: boolean;
extra: string;
}
```

El dato 'inalienable' es boolean y necesito cambiar a string, en caso de ser true, debe mostrar "si".
Y en caso de ser false, debe mostrar "no"

eso.

Comment: Es importante que agregues lo que has intentado hacer para resolver el problema.

Comment: Puedes conseguirlo usando el operador ternario allá donde estés imprimiendo ese valor en el template `{{ inalienable ? 'si' : 'no' }}`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es darle un tipo adicional a ese campo del objeto:

```
    export interface Datos {
       title: string;
       date: string;
       type: string;
       inalienable: boolean | string;
       extra: string;
    }
```

Por lo que le podrás asignar a ese campo (inalienable) el valor de tu preferencia, si bien no es la mejor solución podrás usarlo, para lo que necesitas.

Por ejemplo:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-apiferiados',
      templateUrl: './apiferiados.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./apiferiados.page.scss'],
     })
     export class ApiferiadosPage implements OnInit {

       feriados: Datos[] = [];

       constructor( private feriado:ServiceapiService) { }

       ngOnInit() {

         this.feriado.getFeriados().subscribe(resp => {
           console.log('feriados',resp);
           this.feriados.push(...resp.data);

           this.feriados.forEach(item => {
             item.inalienable = item.inalienable ? 'SI' : 'NO';
           });

         });
       }

     }
```